# d3.js - Why does my SVG tags get added inside the HTML tag

Tags: svg, d3.js

There have been other questions asked about this calendar example:
[Calendar View - http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063318](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063318).

I'm adapting this example for my purposes. 
I added a DIV to the page and I want the SVGs to go into that div.
Here is my modified snippet:

```
var svg = d3.select("#chart") 
    .data(d3.range(2013, 2015))
  .enter().append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("class", "RdYlGn")
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + ((width - cellSize * 53) / 2) + "," + (height - cellSize * 7 - 1) + ")");
```

It actually still works but the SVGs don't go into the DIV.

You can see my example Plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/hkvNyC?p=preview

Here is what the code looks like:

[image]

**What is wrong with the code? 
How do I get the SVGs into the DIV?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `.selectAll('svg')` after selecting the `div`.

```
var svg = d3.select("#chart")
  .selectAll('svg')    // <-- You want to operate on set of SVG elements
    .data(d3.range(2013, 2015))
  .enter().append("svg")
```

Working demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/2SwqI8gW2UaGIdlHvX2Y?p=preview

Also, as a general rule, it is best to run your Javascript code which changes the DOM *after* the DOM has loaded. I have moved the `script` tag which ran your code to the bottom of the `body` tag so that the `div#chart` has been put into the DOM for `d3.select('#chart')` to find.

Comment: Yes, I just saw that edit (the script tag in the body). That is what fixed it. I had the .selectAll('svg') in there before and it would render nothing. I just moved the script tag and it now works as it should. Thanks!